# Codeigniter 3.0 - Can't change database connection dynamically

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I want to change the database connection dynamically, I succeded in codeigniter 2.2.0 but not in 3.0 version.

Here's my code :

```
public function index(){
        $this->load->model('compte_model','compte');
        $this->load->model('utilisateur_model','utilisateur');
        $this->load->helper('database_helper');

        //Getting the database where to connect from the principale database
        $compte = $this->compte->get_by('nom',$this->input->get('nom'));
        $bdd = $compte->bdd_principale;

        //Get the new configuration
        $newDBB = getGroupName($bdd);
        $this->load->database($newDBB,TRUE);

        //Made a query in the second database but it doesn't work
        $users = $this->utilisateur->get_all();

        return $users;
    }
```

Here's the helper function :

```
function getGroupName($bdd){
    $config['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $config['username'] = "root";
    $config['password'] = "";
    $config['database'] = $bdd;
    $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
    $config['dbprefix'] = "";
    $config['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $config['cachedir'] = "";
    $config['char_set'] = "utf8";
    $config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";    

    return $config;
}
```

Comment: Yes, because you'll still be referencing the original DB Connection everywhere you are using $this->db... I'd strongly advise you to read the user guide on this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, I've found the solution:

- First of all, the model in the second database have to be loaded
  after changing the database configuration.
- Second, we have to send parametres of database, as FALSE for the
  returning and TRUE for query_builder.

Finally, the code will be like this:

```
public function index_get(){
        $this->load->model('compte_model','compte');
        $this->load->helper('database_helper');

        $compte = $this->compte->get_by('nom',$this->input->get('nom'));
        $bdd = $compte->bdd_principale;

        //Get the new configuration
        $newDBB = getGroupName($bdd);
        $this->load->database($newDBB,FALSE,TRUE);

        $this->load->model('utilisateur_model','utilisateur');

        $users = $this->utilisateur->get_all();

        return $users;
    }
```

The reason to send this parametres is to change the '$this->db' instance.